# How to trigger a Vue method by name for each element in a v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having troubles triggering a separate Vue instance method by name for each element in a `v-for` loop on click.

Each `action` corresponds to a method, but it's not triggered. What am I doing wrong?

### Code:

```html
<v-btn v-for="btn in windowControlButtons" :key="btn.id"
  @click="btn.action"
>
  <v-icon size="20px">{{btn.icon}}</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

```js
...
window: remote.getCurrentWindow(),
windowControlButtons: [
  {
    icon: 'remove',
    action: minimizeWindow()
  },
  {
    icon: 'crop_square',
    action: maximizeWindow()
  },
  {
    icon: 'close',
    action: closeWindow()
  }
]

...
methods: {
  minimizeWindow() {
    this.window.minimize()
  },
  maximizeWindow() {
    this.window.maximize()
  },
  closeWindow() {
    this.window.close()
  }
}
```

### UPDATE

I can trigger some code directly in the `data()`, e.g.:

```js
...
{
  icon: 'remove',
  action:  () => {remote.getCurrentWindow().minimize()} 
},
```

But what if a method wasn't as short?

How do I trigger a method already specified in `methods: { }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btn.action` is a string, thus you can't execute it.

Every Vue instance/component **method** is accessible as a [**property in the `vm.$options.methods` object**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options).

I suggest creating another method, say `handleClick`, to simplify your method calling depending on the button, and invoke the best suitable method from `this.$options.methods` as shown below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    windowControlButtons: [
      {id: 1, icon: 'remove', action: 'minimizeWindow'},
      {id: 2, icon: 'crop_square', action: 'maximizeWindow'},
      {id: 3, icon: 'close', action: 'closeWindow'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick(button) {
      if (this.$options.methods[button.action]) { // guard to prevent runtime errors
        this.$options.methods[button.action]();
      }
    },
    minimizeWindow() {
      console.log('minimizeWindow');
    },
    maximizeWindow() {
      console.log('maximizeWindow');
    },
    closeWindow() {
      console.log('closeWindow');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-for="btn in windowControlButtons" :key="btn.id" @click="handleClick(btn)">
    <span>{{btn.icon}}</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the code. It's odd that Vue doesn't allow you to just call a specified method. Well, I suppose that's easier said than done

Comment: Yeah. The closer it gets is `this.$options.methods[button.action]()`. I ended up thinking this is safer than `this.[button.action]()`, so I updated the answer. I'm leaving this comment just to let you know.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's some nice clarification there, now I know how that `$options` works as well. Thank you so much!